# ArgumentException when calling Expression.GreaterThanOrEqual via Expression.Call

Tags: c#, entity-framework, reflection, lambda, expression-trees

I get different behaviours when calling `Expression.GreaterThanOrEqual` dynamically or directly.

```
using System;
using System.Linq.Expressions;
using System.Reflection;

namespace ExpressionExample
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            // Build expression head.
            ParameterExpression param = Expression.Parameter(typeof(MyObj), "x");
            MemberExpression property = Expression.Property(param, "MyProperty");

            int value = 1;

            // Build expression body.
            MethodInfo greaterThanOrEqual = typeof(Expression)
                .GetMethod("GreaterThanOrEqual",
                    new[] { typeof(Expression), typeof(Expression) });

            Expression valueExpr = Expression.Convert(Expression.Constant(value),
                property.Type);

            // Dynamic Call
            //var expressionBody = Expression.Call(null, greaterThanOrEqual, property,
                  valueExpr);
            // Direct Call
            var expressionBody = Expression.GreaterThanOrEqual(property, valueExpr);

            // Make Lambda.
            Expression.Lambda<Func<MyObj, bool>>(expressionBody, param);
        }
    }

    class MyObj
    {
        public int MyProperty { get; set; }
    }
}
```

I took the code out of context for simplicity reasons. The Lambda at the end is later used within a where method of a `Queryable`. The direct call works fine and gives expected results. The dynamic call however throws a `System.ArgumentException` saying that `System.Int32`cannot be used as a parameter for the `BinaryExpression` GreaterThanOrEqual. That's actually the reason why I convert the value previously, which is also necessary for the direct call.

What's the difference here? How could I get the dynamic call to work?

Comment: The difference is that what you call *dynamic call* is not a *call* at all. In order to provide you are solution, you need to provide the sample use case where you need that *dynamic call*.

Comment: I updated the question with a minimal and runnable example.

Comment: Ok, but that's not what I need. I understand it's reproducible, but can't find the practical need (the usage case) of dynamic call in order to answer your second question (*how to make it work*).

Comment: I'm working on a Filter (Expression-Tree) which is controlled by json. So you send a request to the API in order to get a list of entities. Which entites the response contains is determined by the (json) filter. The filter is a formula in form of a tree containing boolean algebra. Currently the Equals Expressions are seperated into their own methods. Now I'd like to call them only having the MethodInfo.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I still don't understand the practical usage (hence the need) of your request, so just answering your concrete questions.

> Whats the difference here?

The difference is that `Expression.Call` does not really call the method, but creates a `MethodCallExpression` which *represents* a call to method inside the expression tree. Thus it's not supposed to be used to invoke other `Expression` builder methods.

> How could I get the dynamic call to work?

Instead of `Expression.Call`, you need to simply invoke the methof via reflection:

```
// Dynamic Call
var expressionBody = (Expression)greaterThanOrEqual.Invoke(
    null, new object[] { property, valueExpr });
```